# Erlang package failing to load

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I'm trying to use an Erlang package (this one : https://github.com/komone/qrcode) inside my Phoenix project, so I'm simply trying to get it from my mix file :

```
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.3.0-rc"},
     {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
     {:comeonin, "~> 3.0"},
     {:uuid, "~> 1.1"},
     {:timex, "~> 3.1"},
     {:timex_ecto, "~> 3.1"},
     {:porcelain, "~> 2.0"},
     {:qrcode, git: "https://github.com/komone/qrcode"}, # <--
     {:credo, "~> 0.7", only: [:dev, :test]}]
  end
```

I had to manually `erl -make` inside the fetched directory to make it compile, but at phoenix startup I get the following error :

```
** (Mix) Could not start application qrcode: exited in: :qrcode.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :qrcode.start/2 is undefined or private
            (qrcode) :qrcode.start(:normal, [])
            (kernel) application_master.erl:273: :application_master.start_it_old/4
```

Is there another step to do to make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the convenient mix option to pass :

```
{:qrcode, git: "https://github.com/komone/qrcode", app: false}
```

in order to prevent Mix from trying to load the package application file.

https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Deps.html

Note : you can use the `:compile` option to get rid of the manual compilation of an Emakefile package, in this case :

```
{:qrcode, git: "https://github.com/komone/qrcode", app: false, compile: "erl -make"}
```

Comment: I guess that takes care of the `erlc_paths` too. I just realized my example below was for included Erlang code in my project, not as a dependency.

Comment: Just a note, this is new in Elixir 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

My example below is for including Erlang source in an Elixir project, not as a dependency as the question asked. I'm leave the post here just in case it can help others how are trying to get their Erlang code compiled.

Its been a while since I've done it, but looking back to a previous project, I see the following in my `mix.exs` file:

```
def project do
  [ app: :mdse,
    # ...
    erlc_paths: ["./lib/mdse/rpc/src", "src"]
  ]
end
```

That should get it compile automatically with mix.

After looking at source of the `qrcode` you provided, its not an app. So I don't believe you can add it your `applications:` list. Instead, you should be able to use it as any Erlang library like `:qrcode.encode(...)`.

Comment: :qrcode is not listed in my applications in the mix file, but still Mix seems to try to load it as an application by default.

Comment: @Kernael thanks for sharing that. I've never tried to use a non-app from a dependency before. You may have just saved me some head scratching time in the future.